# is it possible to write words on other pages like google search box from java programs

Tags: java, printing

I saw a macro program that writes words on anywhere when user click a key on keyboard.(write words that user typed in advance)
 But when I study programing  i learned just printing out on console or my project like use "system.out"or "setText/print"

problem
I just tried to get curser focus and write words but i can't go forward.

Is it possible to write something from java project to another programs??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure whether I understood your question correctly, but you can 'inject' user inputs with the AWT Robot API:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html

Here's an [example](https://alvinalexander.com/java/java-robot-class-example-mouse-keystroke) you can take a look at.